# Тестовая страница для отображения данных

Tags: php, битрикс

**Приветствую.**
Сделал тестовый инфоблок, в нем сделал раздел тестовые товары, далее сделал товары.
Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, как и где можно сделать тестовую страницу в которой можно вывести список тех тестовых товаров и детальный просмотр каждого товара по клику.
В битриксе новичек =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Перетаскиваешь компонент Новости на страницу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выбираешь тестовый компонент который ты создал 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А лучше посмотреть ролики на YouTube, так ты быстрей разберешься с битриксом